# Change contour-envoy from NodePort to LoadBalancer

Tags: tanzu-application-service

I have a TKG cluster v 2.3. The contour and envoy instance are set as NodePort. I would like to change it to LoadBalancer. However I cant get this to work.

Updated the tanzu package as follows:

```
tanzu package installed update contour --version 1.24.4+vmware.1-tkg.1 --values-file ./contour-values.yaml --namespace contour-9738b21c
```

The reconciliation is successful.

The contour-values.yaml is as follows:

```
contour:
  replicas: 2
envoy:
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
```

However the envoy service never flips to LoadBalancer and remains as NodePort.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this via the TMC portal. First checked the add-ons and it was managed through TMC. So added an overlay to the add-on with the following:

```
envoy:
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
```

Then hit apply. It took a couple of minutes to reconcile. But after that the service switched to a LoadBalancer.